# ng-repeat Angular and JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to set up a simple display.  I've looked through the documentation on ng-repeat and have done some of the tutorials with success every time.  However, when I went to do a mock of my own I can't get anything to show from the JSON file.  Even using the often found Angular "todo.json" example found everywhere I still am unable to figure this one out.  I'm not sure if it has to do something with JSON or possibly nesting the ng-repeat. Can anyone guide me to seeing the light?! hehe.  Thanks in advance.

So, here's the Plunker link.  http://plnkr.co/edit/8rNgPHUHEe88Gpw6aM1D

HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="App" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Todos $http</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Calendar">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="items in events">
      {{items.events}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('Calendar', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('todos.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.events = res.data;                
        });
});
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "events": [
            {
                "EventTitle": {
                    "href": "http://example.com/event1",
                    "text": "HEADLINE TEXT FOR EVENT 1"
                },
                "HeadlineImage": {
                    "href": "http://example.com/event1",
                    "src": "http://example.com/Image.jpg",
                    "text": "CAPTION TEXT FOR IMAGE "
                },
                "Eventdescription": "Lorem Loreem Loreeem Ipsum Ipsuum Ipsuuum ..."
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must keep this structure, then you need to do something like this

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="items in events">
    <a href="{{items.EventTitle.href}}">{{items.EventTitle.text}}</></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

controller:

```
App.controller('Calendar', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('todos.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.events = res.data[0].events;             
        });
});
```

Here's a [forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JmyL9aRbPFmDlCsBNAOW?p=preview)

Edit:
[The revised plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PzdSWirog1sg9J5VVEMh?p=preview), using the above changes. The scope var should be `res.data.events`

Updating after a new json structure provided:
[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/dzPSwCfHjgS3CaI1KeGB?p=preview) a working example with actual json data

Comment: I edited this, the ng-repeat will work with some modification so chack the revised code. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks this has worked.  Now that I have the JSON working locally, I'm wondering, and forgive me for being so new at this, but how would I interpret this to link to the EXTERNAL JSON file?  I've tried to just put the link in the $Http GET line, but it's not working is there a simple solution to link what is currently the LOCAL json to an EXTERNAL json? I've been scouring StackOverflow for something like this, but all I'm getting is $ajax. Is that the correct way to link an external JSON file in Angular?

Comment: It should work if the get requist is producing exactly this json format, what's the url you are using? Also, have in mind, this functionality should be in a service and then inject the service to the controller.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around this... Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MBrSmZ5SKvLdJjtO24i5?p=preview).  I have also pasted the contents of that JSON file into the todo.json file there.

Comment: The plunker is blocking it because of CORS, try it locally and console.log(res) to see what you are getting and eventually log res.data, res.data[0] to get familiar with how to get what you're looking for.

Comment: I used the actual json, check updated answer for a working example from the real json.

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure is pretty weird. Check an updated working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/SXHjqxjZ2bgJSs327jz4?p=preview

You can use `<pre>{{ events | json }}</pre>` in your view to easily inspect/debug objects.

Comment: Hmm.. Is there anyway to work within this particular format since the API is structuring the JSON like this directly from kimono.io?